# Averiguar tipografñia Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, unix, centos

Me gustaría saber como listar la tipografía que se está utilizando en el shell de linux.
Se que con fc-list puedo listar los nombres de las tipografías, pero me interesa sacar la que está en uso.

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Estás usando un desktop gráfico? ¿Qué programa usas como emulador de terminal en ese caso? ¿O estás usando la consola de texto?

Comment: estoy trabajando en la propia consola de linux

Comment: La consola de linux (la terminal física, esa negra con letras blancas) no usa las tipografías de x-window. De hecho no puede usar formatos tipográficos TTF, OTF, u otros vectoriales, sino sólo sus propios y específicos tipos bitmap. Puedes ver cuál estás usando mirando el archivo `/etc/default/console-setup`